# MySQL not updating row consistently?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have the following code which sends an AJAX POST to a php file on my server to add a row into a MySQL table. This function gets run when a user marks an item as their favorite:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'school='+school+'&token='+token,
    url: 'http://www.codekraken.com/testing/snowday/database9.php',
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(){
    console.log(data);
    }
 });
```

I also have a similar function that runs when they delete the favorite:

```
data: 'school=&token='+token,
```

This works, but not consistently. The PHP code is below:

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";
$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$token = $_POST["token"];
$school = $_POST["school"];

if (strlen($token) == 0){
    die('Incorrect token');
}

if (strlen($school) == 0){
    die('Invalid school name');
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO Snow (Token, School, Skip) ";
$sql .= "VALUES ('$token', '$school', '0') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE School='$school'";

if (!mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    echo "$token, $school = Success";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

What I mean by it not working consistently is that if I mark one item as the favorite, it will create a row. If I unmark it, it will change `$school` to nothing. If I then mark a different item, it will change to that item. **IF**, however, I try marking the first item as a favorite, it won't update, but will retain the last change.

So, it seems that it's only updating the row each time something new happens, but not if the value has already been present even though it's not CURRENTLY present.

**NOTE:** Column `Token` is indexed as a `UNIQUE PRIMARY`

The JS code that pertains to `var school`:

```
function setFavorite() {
    var threshold = {
        x: 30,
        y: 10
    };
    var originalCoord = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    var finalCoord = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

    function touchMove() {
        finalCoord.x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
        changeX = originalCoord.x - finalCoord.x;
        var changeY = originalCoord.y - finalCoord.y;
        if (changeY < threshold.y && changeY > (threshold.y * -1)) {
            changeX = originalCoord.x - finalCoord.x;
            if (changeX > threshold.x) {
                window.removeEventListener('touchmove', touchMove, false);
                $(document).off("touchmove", ".row");
                if ($(event.target).attr("class") === "row-inside") {
                    var element = $(event.target);
                }
                if ($(event.target).attr("class") === "row-l") {
                    var element = $(event.target).parent();
                }
                if ($(event.target).attr("class") === "row-r") {
                    var element = $(event.target).parent();
                }
                var text = $(element).find(".row-l").text();

                var token = window.deviceToken;
                var school = $(element).find(".row-l").text();

                var favstatus = $(element).find(".row-r").text();
                var thisStar = $(element).parent().find(".star-inside");
                $(element).css("margin-left", "-75px");
                if ($(thisStar).hasClass("favorite")) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: 'school=&token=' + token,
                        url: 'http://www.codekraken.com/testing/snowday/database10.php',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                    $(".clear span").text("");
                    $(thisStar).removeClass("favorite");
                    localStorage.removeItem("favorite");
                    localStorage.removeItem("favorite-status");
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: 'school=' + school + '&token=' + token,
                        url: 'http://www.codekraken.com/testing/snowday/database10.php',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                    $(".clear span").text("\"" + text + "\"");
                    localStorage.setItem("favorite", text);
                    localStorage.setItem("favorite-status", favstatus);
                    $(".star-inside").not(thisStar).removeClass("favorite");
                    $(thisStar).addClass("favorite");
                }
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(element).css("margin-left", "0px");
                }, 500);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(document).on("touchmove", ".row", function () {
                        touchMove();
                    });
                }, 800);
            }
        }
    }

    function touchStart() {
        originalCoord.x = event.targetTouches[0].pageX;
        finalCoord.x = originalCoord.x;
    }
    $(document).on("touchmove", ".row", function () {
        touchMove();
    });
    $(document).on("touchstart", ".row", function () {
        touchStart();
    });
}
```

MySQL Output:

```
CREATE TABLE `Snow` (
 `Token` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `School` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `Skip` int(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Token`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicod
```

Comment: instead of explaining this in terms of logical user actions which are hard to understand what you mean, give us examples of the exact parameters you call the script with, and the result, including script output.  Show us examples where you call the script, and get a result different from what you want.

Comment: The script output is always the correct output `2012-10-24 22:04:00.693 Snow Day[1651:907] [INFO] TOKEN, SCHOOL = Success` where TOKEN and SCHOOL are the actual values. The JS is called just how you see it. When you click a `div`, it runs the first script, sending the request, and subsequently adding it as a favorite. Then clicking it again removes it, and runs the second part of JS, setting SCHOOL to nothing. It's all posted to the PHP script, which returns the output above. Like I said, it's only not updating the row once it's been updated with a previous value.

Comment: We need to see how the variable `school` is defined in the JS though.  Where it's collected from, and what potential collisions it may encounter.

Comment: I'll update the post. The variable has never had any other problems on the page, only in this scenario, so I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: also, please show the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE Snow \G

Comment: Updated with the output, although \G was giving me an error, so I omitted it.

Comment: One more peculiar thing to note: It seems that databaseX.php is being cached by the AJAX post (which doesn't make sense to me). When I make a change to the PHP file on my server, and then try running the function from my app, it will not use the changes that I just made. If I change the file name, however, it will then take into account the changes. Like I said, might just be a cache problem, but it also might be something more.

Comment: maybe getting verbose warning logs from php would be helpful (and also checking your last error values after insert is done)

Comment: The thing is that no errors are presented to me on the PHP side. By this I mean that runs fine without any errors whatsoever. Unless there could be errors specific to MySQL, in which case, where would I find them?

Comment: Have you tried echoing the SQL statement and executing them manually in something like phpMyAdmin to see if the statements work/cause errors?

Comment: try to set error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT); to catch the more obscure mistakes. Also, use mysql_real_escape_string, otherwise anyone can destroy your database if magic_quotes_gpc are off.

Comment: It seems magic_quotes_gpc are on, but this might be different on a production system.

Comment: Matt, they work fine through phpMyAdmin and update the row without fail. Adder, I'll try this when I get home, although I received the same results when using mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem seemed to be with Phonegap caching the AJAX request. I then thought if I added `cache: false,` to the AJAX request, it would solve it, but once again, no dice.

I then googled around a bit, and found the piece of code that made it work:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); xhr.setRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache"); },
```

You put that within your AJAX request, so it would look something like:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
    },
    type: 'POST',
    ...
});
```

---

I'm not entirely sure if it can work without also setting `cache: false`, but I don't feel like rocking the boat. I also specified within my PHP code these headers:

```
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Turns out the immediate above is not nescesary, but I'll leave it here in case it helps someone else.